# Удалить слушатель

Tags: c#, unity3d

Assets/Scripts/TutorialController.cs(72,79): error CS0039: Cannot convert type `void' to`UnityEngine.Object' via a built-in conversion

```
foreach (GameObject btn in  buttonsNumber) {
    (Ошибка, 72,79) Destroy(btn.GetComponent<Button> ().onClick.AddListener (CheckClickNumber)as Object);
            }
```

Подскажите  :)

Comment: onClick.RemoveListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (GameObject btn in  buttonsNumber) 
{
    btn.GetComponent<Button> ().onClick.RemoveListener();            
}
```